# Check if set values exists in Matrix

Tags: matlab

The matrix <1x500> contains different values, I am trying to do an if-statement to check if there is 3 different values, lets say it somewhere must contain 30, 40 and 50 in order to evaluate to true. They don't have to come in order.

I tried:

```
if all any(val == 30) && any(val == 40) && any(val == 50)
   do stuff
```

But it's not really working as intended, it seems it evaluate to true if only one of the values exists.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have an extra and unnecessary `all` in there. You can use simply

```
if any(val == 30) && any(val == 40) && any(val == 50)
```

Alternately,  you could use `ismember` to simultaneously check for all values in the input.

```
if ismember([30 40 50], val)
```

Comment: You can also use `intersect` and see if the intersection is empty or not.

Comment: @BlackAdder That wouldn't be sufficient because `intersect([30 40 50], 30)` is non-empty

Comment: True, I read incorrectly. Checking if non-empty will work for checking if ANY of the values are in the Matrix. To check if ALL the values are in the matrix you can check if the size of the intersection is equal to the size of the vector you are looking (assuming it contains unique values)

Comment: Thanks for the help!